# how to have re.sub work for multiple pattern replace on list of list?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of list
input- old_list:

```
[['hi.','pt','patient','med',...],
['.','md','pt','md',...]...]
```

my desired output - new_list:

```
[['hi',' ',' ','medication',...],
[' ', 'medication', ' ',...]...]
```

and I have tried

1.

```
adict = {"\.": " ",
        "patient": " ",
        "\bpt\b": " ",
        "\bmed\b":"medication"}
```

```py
for key, value in adict.items():
    new_list= [[re.sub(key, value, e) for e in d] for d in old_list]
```

2. 

```
replacements = [('\.', ""),
                ("patient"," "),
                ("\bpt\b", " "),
                ("\bmed\b","medication")]
```

```py
for old, new in replacements:
    new_list=[]
    new_list= [[re.sub(old, new, e) for e in d] for d in old_list]
```

3. and `replace(new_list, old, new) for ...`

but none of them works, the output is the same as the original old_list.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Tip: never call variables `dict`, `list`, or other built-in names.

Comment: edited. just an example here but used other names in my actual codes

Comment: Can you give an example input and expected/desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to use output of each iteration as input for a next iteration, i.e. `in new_list` instead of `in old_list`. And of course to initialize the variable before loop: `new_list = old_list`.
2. Regex patterns should have `r`-prefix.
3. As mentioned in comments, avoid naming variables with built-in names like `dict` and `list`.

```py
import re

patterns = {
    r"\.": " ",
    r"patient": " ",
    r"\bpt\b": " ",
    r"\bmed\b": "medication",
}
old_list = [['hi.', 'pt', 'patient', 'start med end'], ['.', 'md', 'pt', 'md']]

new_list = old_list
for key, value in patterns.items():
    new_list = [[re.sub(key, value, e) for e in d] for d in new_list]

print(old_list)
print(new_list)
```

Comment: ah I see thank u very much! After adding the first 2 items you mentioned it works now.

Comment: The `r''` prefix is not strictly necessary or specific to regex; but you have to understand how it affects backslashes. If your regex doesn't contain backslashes or you know how you need to double-escape them, that's fine; but of course, in practice, always using `r''` strings for your regular expressions (and Windows paths) is a recommended and simple good practice.